# Customizing All Views of Document Library To Open Another Form Page On Any File Upload Action

Tags: document-library, spfx, modern-experience, file-upload, jslink

I've seen a couple of posts in this forum that are somewhat related to users wanting to set up a custom upload form which requires users set metadata (column values) before an upload is permitted. I have created such a form (inside & outside SP chrome) using the SP REST API and have given the URL to that form.

Lead user wants all the views of the list to divert to this URL whenever there is any file upload (drag-n-drop, use of Upload function in modern experience) action/event taken. This is probably do-able using JSLink in classic experience, but we are moving completely towards the modern experience. Does anyone have advice to offer as to what customization in SPFx I should be looking at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to be creating an SpFx extension.  Specifically you will want to create what is called a List View Command Set.  Your best starting points (other than google) are these two GitHub repos:

- [Getting Started - Building Your First SpFx Extension](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/blob/master/docs/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-simple-cmdset-with-dialog-api.md)
- [SpFx Samples](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-extensions/tree/main/samples)

Comment: I was wondering if that was the direction in which to go, and you confirmed.

Comment:  glad to help